# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions: System.IO.FileNotFoundException only on build server version

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, deployment, entity-framework-core

I get an error that says a file was not found. If I compile the program locally, it works.
**Only the version compiled on the build server fails when run locally.**

```
Unhandled exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<GetOrAdd>g__BuildServiceProvider|4_1(IDbContextOptions _, ValueTuple`2 arguments)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c.<GetOrAdd>b__4_0(IDbContextOptions contextOptions, ValueTuple`2 tuples)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor()
   at MyProject.Models.DbContext..ctor() in c:\path\to\ci\pipeline\MyProject\Models\DbContext.cs:line 12
```

If it is important: The Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore is used by several projects in the solution.
Can this have something to do with the CopyLocal property?

**EDIT:**
I have now identified the problem in another place: Some nuget package uses Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions in version 2.0.0. Which one it is exactly is not known, but it seems that this version is added to the output. Strangely, Visual Studio does not show any Nuget conflicts.

Comment: Does your build server delete previous builds before each build?  Either that file is missing from the published artifact, or something it depends on is missing from your system.  The path `c:\path\to\ci\pipeline` is just to help you with debugging, that path is not the one that is missing, `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` is missing.

Comment: @Neil Yes all previous files are deleted

Comment: Is the missing DLL in your bin folder? If so, which version? Probably the project you're building uses an X version and a dependency is using a different version of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions. If that's the problem you could try to match the versions or using bindingRedirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I finally found the problem. An old Windows Forms app seems to have an implicit dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions`. In the Obj folder you could see a dependency on version 2.0.0. The build server compiles all projects in the solution sequentially, so the 2.0.0 version always ended up last in the bin folder, overwriting the 7.0.0. Locally the behavior is probably different due to parallel compilation.
**Solution:**
Change the output path for the Windows Forms app and not compile everything into one folder.